# Correct approach of setting up fluent nhibernate syscache with one table and four queries?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

My scenario is pretty simple, I have 1 table with about 20 products that I would like to add to level 2 cache (SysCache) using Fluent NHibernate. I query this table 4 different ways so I figure I'd stick the whole thing in cache every so often and reduce the database hits.

My 4 queries are:

1. All(start, max) for paging
2. ByDate(date) for getting products before or after a certain date
3. ById(id)
4. ByName(name)

I have enabled SysCache in the fluent configuration using the code below and added the appropriate configuration to web.config.

```
MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.Cache(c => c.ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>()
                                         .UseQueryCache())
```

I added the following code to the ProductMap

```
Cache.ReadWrite().Region("testregion");
```

Now how do I proceed from here? Do I have to add SetCachable(true) to all my 4 queries? Is that the correct approach?

Part of me thinks that there should be a way to cache an All() query and then point the 4 above queries to use the cached All() to query against. Maybe my assumptions are dead wrong and every query does need to be added to cache separately using SetCachable(true) on a query level.

What is the correct approach to setup cache for this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query caching is enabled individually. There are no shortcuts built-in.

Of course you could add an extension method, or use a base class that does that, but it's really not worth it: wholesale caching rarely improves the performance.